# Laravel Lumen 8: MethodNotAllowedHttpException Only for post routes on remote server

Tags: laravel, lumen

There are branches `dev` and `master` in the repository and two production and staging servers are created from these branches on `xxx.com` and `xxx.dev`. Both branches are the same in this moment. The problems is `post` routes are working in production but in staging server `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is reported for `post` routes, but `GET` routes are OK. No UI exists and this is just api. Here is route

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('pay', 'PaymentController@pay');
    $router->get('list', 'PaymentController@list');
});
```

I use postman to call the routes.

The `.env` file of both servers are the same expecting the database configuration and urls. All `.com` are changed to `.dev`

What is wrong here?

Comment: occasional culprits are (301, 302) redirects like e.g. an http to https redirect or similar

Comment: @apokryfos You are right. The `https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php` shows me a 302 to https. The route with https works

Comment: If you set `APP_SSL=true` then (hopefully) any URLs generated by Laravel will be https so that might help

Comment: @apokryfos at .env file?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clear the routes cache?

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: No, But I try it and let u know the results